# how read array Multidimensional by key in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

this my reault from server

```
Array ( [id] => 123 [status] => pending [recipient] => Array ( [account_id] => 5000 [gateway_id] => 51111 ) [amount] => Array ( [value] => 2 [currency] => RUB ) [description] => order test 1 [payment_method] => Array ( [type] => bank_card [id] => 123 [saved] => ) [created_at] => 2018-08-05T14:44:59+00:00 [confirmation] => Array ( [enforce] => [confirmation_url] => https://money.com/1234566 [type] => redirect ) [paid] => )
```

how i can get **confirmation_url** string ?

tnx

Comment: Are you `print_r()`'ing the result, and you want to parse *that* string in your javascript? This is something `json_encode()` (PHP) and `JSON.parse()` (javascript) was specifically designed for.

Comment: this print_r result in php , i can not get value in confirmation_url  when i used $json[confirmation] return    **Array ( [enforce] => [confirmation_url] => https://money.com/1234566 [type] => redirect )** but i need get   confirmation_url

Comment: This question is quite unclear: How are you getting this? Where are you echoing it out? Is this an API call through AJAX, or are you just echoing out PHP afterwards?

Comment: @FrankerZ it is very similar to `print_r`

Comment: @NaeimRezaeian `[enforce] => [confirmation_url]` this is very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access like

```
$array['confirmation']['confirmation_url']
```

Comment: tnx a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save that as a variable. So, let's say the array came from a CURL function called "validateTransaction()";

```
$result = validateTransaction();
$confirmationUrl = $result['confirmation']['confirmation_url'];
```

As a pro tip - I prefer to use 'json_encode($result);' to put the array in a readable format, and then put the input into a wonderful site called http://jsonselector.com, where you can select the value and see the proper "selector" to get the value out of an array.

Of course, this doesn't really tell us *how* you're getting that data response.

If it's formatted as XML and you're parsing it with SimpleXmlElement, then you can do a json_decode(json_encode($result),true); to convert an XML element to "proper" array.